# Python Holoviews - Update plots with slider

Tags: python, slider, panel, holoviews

I have some code that makes two plots and a slider out of a dataframe. The slider is a IntRangeSlider, and I would like to show the data taken between the two weeks defined by the slider.
However, I don't manage to do it: I have the slider and the plots but they won't update when I use the slider. Could anyone give me a hand to find out what's wrong?

My database is something like this:

|  | column1 | Column2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-04-30 22:00:00+00:00 | 101.4 | 45.5 |
| 2022-04-30 22:03:00+00:00 | 259.5 | 38.4 |

And this is the code I have tried:

```
class CreatePlot:

    def _leg_plot(self, data, colors):
        empty = pd.DataFrame(index=[data.index[0]], columns=['parameter'])
        empty['parameter'] = 0.
        return {c: hv.Scatter(empty, label=str(c)).opts(color=colors[c], responsive=True) for c in colors}

    def create_datashaded_time_series(self, data: DataFrame, hist=False, kind="hist", y_range=None, title='', xlabel='Time', ylabel=None, height=430, hist_width=150, active_tools=['box_zoom'], color_palette=Viridis, responsive=True, xrotation=45, **kwargs) -> DynamicMap:
       
        def week(datesarg):
            year = pd.to_datetime(data.index[0]).year
            if year == 2021:
                yearstart = datetime(2021, 1, 4, 9, 0, 0, 0, pytz.UTC)
            elif year == 2022:
                yearstart = datetime(2022, 1, 3, 9, 0, 0, 0, pytz.UTC)
            elif year == 2023:
                yearstart = datetime(2023, 1, 2, 9, 0, 0, 0, pytz.UTC)
            timediff = datesarg - yearstart
            weeknumber = (timediff.days // 7) + 1
            return (weeknumber)

        else:

            data_columns = data.columns
            if len(data_columns) <= 2:
                colors = [c for c in color_palette[3]]
            else:
                colors = [c for c in color_palette[len(data_columns)]]
            colors = dict(zip([col for col in data_columns], colors))

            scatter_dict, hist_dict = hv_elements(data, flag="app", colors=colors, num_bins=500, y_range=y_range, kind=kind)

            curve_overlay = hv.NdOverlay(scatter_dict, kdims='cols')

            ds_curve_overlay = dynspread(
                datashade(curve_overlay,
                          aggregator=ds.count_cat('cols'),
                          y_range=y_range,
                          color_key=colors)).opts(
                # width=1500,
                height=height,
                title=title,
                xlabel=xlabel,
                ylabel=ylabel,
                xrotation=xrotation,
                active_tools=active_tools,
                hooks=[hv_dateformatter],
                responsive=responsive,
                **kwargs)

           
             lnk_sel = link_selections.instance()   ########

             h = hv.NdOverlay(hist_dict)

             invert_axes = True
             ylabel = 'Number of cycles' 


             h.opts(width=hist_width,
                       height=height,
                       xticks=xticks,
                       xrotation=xrotation,
                       invert_axes=invert_axes,
                       xlabel='',
                       ylabel=ylabel,
                       )

             dmap = (ds_curve_overlay).opts(height=height, width=1150-hist_width)

             linked_dmap = lnk_sel(dmap)

### I create the slider:
             start_week = 1
             end_week = 52
             week_selector = pn.widgets.IntRangeSlider(
                    name='Week selection',
                    start=start_week,
                    end=end_week,
                    value=(end_week, end_week),
                    step=1
                    )

### I create a function to update the data:
             @pn.depends(week_selector.param.value)
             def filter_data(week_range):
                    start, end = week_range

                    data['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(data.index, unit='ns', utc=True)
                    data['week_number'] = data['datetime'].apply(lambda x: week(x))

                    filtered_data = data.loc[(data['week_number'] >= 1) &
                                             (data['week_number'] <= 52)]

                    filtered_data = filtered_data.drop(['week_number', 'datetime'], axis=1)
                    return self.create_datashaded_time_series(filtered_data, hist, kind, y_range, title, xlabel,ylabel, height, hist_width, active_tools, color_palette,responsive, xrotation, **kwargs)

                panel = pn.Column(
                      pn.Row(filter_data),
                      pn.Row(linked_dmap, h),
                      sizing_mode='stretch_width')

                return panel.servable()
```

I also tried another option, I changed the function filter_data by this one:

```
                @pn.depends(week_selector.param.value)
                def update(week_range):
                    start, end = week_range
                    data['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(data.index, unit='ns', utc=True)
                    data['week_number'] = data['datetime'].apply(lambda x: week(x))

                    filtered_data = data.loc[(data['week_number'] >= start) &
                                             (data['week_number'] <= end)]

                    filtered_data = filtered_data.drop(['week_number', 'datetime'], axis=1)
                    scatter_dict, hist_dict = hv_elements(filtered_data, flag="app", colors=colors, num_bins=500,
                                                          y_range=y_range,
                                                          kind=kind)

                    curve_overlay = hv.NdOverlay(scatter_dict, kdims='cols')

                    ds_curve_overlay.data = datashade(curve_overlay,
                                                      aggregator=ds.count_cat('cols'),
                                                      y_range=y_range,
                                                      color_key=colors)
                    h.data = hist_dict
```

And then I added a row to the panel:

```
pn.Row(filter_data)
```

But none of them make the plot update through the slider.

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it using a different approach:

https://panel.holoviz.org/how_to/interactivity/bind_function.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).